# Vuetify V-File-Input Multiple Files

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Pretty straightforward. Trying to get multiple files to display but the only one will since there is always only one in the array. When adding another file, the one uploaded before it gets overwritten. this.files is always just one file and and wont add on instead. How can I add on to files, instead of always overwriting? Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
<v-file-input
  v-model="files"
  small-chips
  show-size
  multiple
  clearable
>
  <template v-slot:selection="{ text, index, file }">
    <v-chip
      small
      text-color="white"
      color="#295671"
      close
      @click:close="remove(index)"
    >
      {{ text }}
    </v-chip>
  </template>
</v-file-input>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    files: []
  }),
  methods: {
    remove (index) {
      this.files.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Working Example: https://codepen.io/jhernandez_dev/pen/YzzRxMq?&editable=true&editors=101#anon-signup

Comment: Let me ask you for a short ques, **You want to select, show and upload multiple files?**

Comment: if you are uploading multiple files, then `this.files` should be an array containing a list of multiple file objects. Have you inspected `this.files` in the Vue Devtools right after you select and upload multiple files?

Comment: @GurkiratSingh I want to be able to upload more than one, show chips. I already have the ability to delete so thats fine. Just having issues with having more than one files in this.files. Its always overwritten when adding another files

Comment: @Angelo Yes I have. this.files anytime I upload a file is overwritten instead of adding another to the array. When I console.log this.files onChange its always shows the most recently added, but never any of the ones added beforehand.

Comment: Added codepen example in post to see exactly what im seeing

Comment: @Zeus do you want me to post the solution or just tell you an approach?

Comment: @GurkiratSingh Either would be greatly appreciated. Any help would be awesome. Feel I'm missing something so simple...

Comment: why not just remove `clearable`? then files will be added instead of clearing previous

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by merging 2 file arrays. One for the *current* selected files, and another for *all* files...

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    currFiles: [],
    files: []
  }),
  methods: {
    remove (index) {
      this.files.splice(index, 1)
    },
    inputChanged () {
      console.log(this.files)
      this.files = [
          ...this.currFiles,
          ...this.files
      ]
    }
  }  
})
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/p/nbJbuftXPH)

Answer (score 2):

You can do one thing

1. Create a hidden `input` tag and add a reference to it
2. Create a `v-select` component with prepend icon and append outer icon as a part of actions

**Template**

```html
<input type="file" hidden multiple ref="files" @change="listFiles">
<v-select
  v-model="files"
  :items="files"
  chips
  readonly
  prepend-icon="attach_file"
  multiple
  @click="$refs.files.click()"
  @click:prepend="$refs.files.click()"
  @click:append-outer="uploadHere"
  label="Files"
  append-icon
  append-outer-icon="cloud_upload"
></v-select>
```

**Script**

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      files: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    listFiles() {
      this.files = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.$refs.files.files.length; i++)
        this.files.push(this.$refs.files.files[i].name);
    },
    uploadHere()
    {
      console.log("Uploading");
      let formData = new FormData();

      // iteratate this.$refs.files.files

      // add data to formData

      // Post the form data with 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' via fetch or Axios
    
      console.log("Uploaded");
      this.files = []
    }
  },
  created() {}
};
```

PS: This is an approach. If you find any difficulty in understanding, comment below

Comment: Does this mean what I'm trying to accomplish wouldn't work with vuetify's v-file-input? Thank you for helping me understand another approach.

Comment: @Zeus the problem is I haven't used v-file-input so this works well in my case. If you got another solution, you can too answer your question and help us

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing something like this.

```html
<template>
  <v-file-input
    id="uploadedfiles"
    v-model="files"
    show-size
    counter
    multiple
    clearable
    label="File input"
    name="uploadedfiles"
    :rules="[filesizeLimit]"
    @change="inputChanged"
  >
    <template #selection="{ index, text }">
      <v-chip small label close color="primary" @click:close="deleteChip(index, text)">{{ text }}</v-chip>
    </template>
  </v-file-input>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    deleteChip(index, text) {
      // Prompt here with text if required
      this.previousFiles.splice(index, 1)
      this.files = this.previousFiles
    },
    inputChanged() {
      this.files = []
      const uploadedFiles = this.$refs.form.$el.querySelector('#uploadedfiles').files
      for (let i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.length; i++) {
        if (
          this.previousFiles !== undefined &&
          this.previousFiles !== null &&
          this.previousFiles.length <= 0
        ) {
          this.previousFiles.push(uploadedFiles[i])
        } else {
          const index = this.previousFiles.findIndex((x) => x.name === uploadedFiles[i].name)
          if (index >= 0) {
            this.previousFiles.splice(index, 1)
          }
          this.previousFiles.push(uploadedFiles[i])
        }
      }
      this.files = this.previousFiles
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was to add multiple files from multiple locations on the drive.

I succeed to achieve that by adding a simple watcher :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    currFiles: [],
    previousFiles: [],
    files: []
  }),
  watch: {
    files(val) {
        this.previousFiles = val
    }  
  },
  methods: {
    remove (index) {
      this.files.splice(index, 1)
    },
    fileAdded () {
      console.log(this.files)
      if (this.previousFiles.length > 0) {
        this.files.push(...this.previousFiles)
      }
    }
  }  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <v-app>
        <div class="container">
            <v-file-input v-model="files" 
                small-chips 
                :show-size="1000"
                counter
                outlined
                placeholder="Select your files"
                multiple 
                clearable 
                label="Add files"
                @change="fileAdded">
                <template v-slot:selection="{ text, index, file }">
                    <v-chip small text-color="white" color="#295671" close @click:close="remove(index)">
                        {{ text }}
                    </v-chip>
                </template>
            </v-file-input>
        </div>
    </v-app>
</div>
```

[Demo CodePly](https://www.codeply.com/p/0baTMSlmYE)